# grouping my widgets wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, widgets

In the widgets page, there are two boxes "Available Widgets" and "Inactive Widgets". How can I add a new boxe with my custom name where I can group all my widgets.

Comment: What has been your research so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. More info about how to ask a good question can be found in the [help/how-to-ask] pages.

Comment: @kaiser hhhhh !